# How to disable font scaling in React Native for IOS And Android app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Enlargement of size of the device font will sometimes break (Styling wise).

Comment: This is a bad choice because it hurts users with poor eyesight, and users with shaky hands or other motor issues that make it hard to interact with small touch targets. A better solution is to fix your styling so font changes don't break it. (For example, don't use fixed heights or widths.)

Comment: It's not always the case @AaronBrager, on small device its almost impossible to "fix" your styling to fit text on same row. So unless you don't have much text to view on your screen then yes you can be more considerate. So this is totally optional and not obligatory. What ever fits your need you do so.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be on the same row. Users who turn their font size all the way up are happy to have awkward text wrapping.

Comment: Well in case the project owner doesn't want their app to break like that they can use this. Else they can totally ignore this and keep the font on auto size. Again this is totally optional. @AaronBrager

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Disabling font scaling can hurt the accessibility of your app, ideally if you want to limit scaling for Apps using React native 0.58.0 and above; use the [`maxFontSizeMultiplier` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#maxfontsizemultiplier) on specific `Text` components.

However if you absolutely want to disable font scaling across your entire Application, you can do so by globally setting the [`allowFontScaling` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#allowfontscaling) in the `defaultProps` of `Text`.

You should place these lines in your root entrypoint (normally `index.js`) before `AppRegistry.registerComponent`.

For React Native 0.56.0+

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

For earlier versions of React Native you should only need the second line, but having both won't hurt. The first line just protects against the `Text` component not having `defaultProps` which is the case for React Native 0.56.0 and above.

Add the above lines in the entry point file of your React Native application (usually `index.js`, `app.js` or `main.js`) to apply this prop to all `Text` components in your application.

This prop will only affect `Text` components and you may want to apply the same changes to `TextInput` which can be done with a similar snippet:

```
TextInput.defaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps || {};
TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Also note that some components wont obey font scaling settings, for example: `Alert`, `PickerIOS`, `DatePickerIOS`, `TabBarIOS`, `SegmentedControlIOS` as these are all natively drawn and don't rely on the `Text` component.

Comment: Hackish, but brilliant nevertheless. Am using it.

Comment: @KiritModi I think Alert is rendered entirely natively -- so I'm guessing you're unable to control how text is rendered inside the modal. Instead you'd need to implement your own alert component.

Comment: In case some of you are wondering where to implement this, place the above code right below your import statements in `~/index.js`. Be sure to also import the `Text` component into RN. BTW, I'm running RN 0.57.8.

Comment: Text.defaultProps can sometimes be undefined, so it's better to use: `Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}`. It handles both cases.

Comment: @dphaener the original checked for `Text.defaultProps` being undefined.

Answer (score 46):

For React native 0.58+

Preferable to keep font scaling but you can limit it by using Text new prop [maxFontSizeMultiplier](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#maxfontsizemultiplier)

For React native 0.56+ use [Levi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414341/6747076)

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

For React native 0.55 and lower

Add `Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false` at the beginning of the app (e.g. main.js or app.js etc ...) to apply this prop on all Text components through out the whole app.

Comment: When i add it to constructor in App.js, i get error, do i miss something?

Comment: @AnshulKoka can you confirm this ? I was checking the documentation and didn't see  anything concerning default props and allowFontScalling.

Comment: @A-J-A I just upgraded from react-native 0.55.4 to 0.56.0 today and Text.defaultProps comes out as undefined.

Answer (score 14):

```
When user increase full font size from setting
```

Enlargement of size of the device font will not break (Styling wise).

```
index.js file


import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

//ADD this 
if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
    Text.defaultProps = {};
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}

if (TextInput.defaultProps == null) {
    TextInput.defaultProps = {};
    TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}

<CalendarStrip
    shouldAllowFontScaling={false}
/>
```

Also note that some components wont obey font scaling settings, for example: Alert, PickerIOS, DatePickerIOS, TabBarIOS, SegmentedControlIOS as these are all natively drawn and don't rely on the Text component.

Answer (score 6):

I'm kinda late, but if anyone wants a answer with Typescript, here it is

```js
interface TextWithDefaultProps extends Text {
  defaultProps?: { allowFontScaling?: boolean };
}

(Text as unknown as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps = {
   ...((Text as unknown as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {}),
   allowFontScaling: false,
 };
```

Comment: If you want to allow scaling but not too much you can adapt this solution like this: interface TextWithDefaultProps extends Text {
  defaultProps?: { maxFontSizeMultiplier?: number };
}
  (Text as unknown as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps = {
    ...((Text as unknown as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {}),
    maxFontSizeMultiplier: 1.1,
  };

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
            Text.defaultProps = {};
            Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
        }
```

I kept this piece of code inside the constructor of `index.js`.It really worked well. By the I am using react native version `0.59.9` FYI.

Comment: `Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {} ;`
`Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;`

This is equivalent to your code

Answer (score 2):

## For IOS

`index.js`

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('appName', () => App);

if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
    Text.defaultProps = {};
    Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}
```

**Note** that some components like **Alert**, **PickerIOS**, **DatePickerIOS**, **TabBarIOS**, and **SegmentedControlIOS** won't obey font scaling settings as they are natively drawn and don't rely on the Text component.

## For Android

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());
  }

  private void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.0;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `<AppText>` component and use it with your presets instead of the original one, with your own default, including font scaling false. This is better because you can enrich it with your own API.

For example, my AppText permit to do things like:

`<AppText id="some.translation.key" color="primary" size="l" underline italic bold/>`

Comment: Might be what you need in some circumstances, but what do you do if e.g. you want ReactNavigation to restrict the font scaling in `MaterialCommunityIcons` used in `headerRight`? Unfortunately using `<MaterialCommunityIcons name="magnify" allowFontScaling={false}" />` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In another file, import the actual `Text` component as `ScaledText` so as a backup, and then redefine `Text`, overriding the `allowFontScaling` prop.

```
export function Text(props) {
  return <ScaledText {...props} allowFontScaling={false} />;
}
```

Then, import your locally defined `Text` component, instead of the built-in React Native `Text`. This is also useful if you want to elegantly disable font scaling on only certain parts of your app.

Answer (score 1):

For webview we can use `textZoom={100}` props to handle font-size change if font size is changed from mobile setting.

if imported from `react-native-webview`

```
<WebView
    textZoom={100}
    source={}/>
```