# allowFontScaling={false}` doesn't work with TextInput's placeholder

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

When I set `allowFontScaling={false}` for `TextInput` must be Text size don't be scaled.(It's right.)

but Placeholder size still be scaled (I think that it's unreasonable.).

how to set `allowFontScaling={false}` for TextInput's placeholder ???

my code:

```
<TextInput placeholder="my placeholder" allowFontScaling={false}/>
```

Comment: You can try styling it with css: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Comment: "Add Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false at the beginning of the app (e.g. main.js or app.js etc ...) to apply this prop on all Text components through out the whole app." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app

Comment: @Omar - I added this but still have this problem

Comment: It is because because you must replace Text by TextInput (I guess)

Comment: You can also use the module [react-native-global-props](https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props) to set global default props to one particular set of component (use the setCustomTextInput function that this lib exports)