# React Native Text.defaultProps does not exist and creating it doesn't work either

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-text

I'm new to React Native (0.59.3) and I'm trying to set default font for all `Text` components in my app. I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47925418/811405 and [How to disable font scaling in React Native for IOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app/51414341).

In my `App.js` I've put:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

Text.defaultProps.style = { 
  fontFamily: 'AmericanTypewriter' //just for testing
}
```

But I get `Cannot set property 'style' of undefined`.

When I add the line `Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};` before that, I don't get an error, but nothing happens (all `Text` components still use the default font). I've tried with different fonts (both built-in iOS fonts and my custom fonts that I've linked and verified), using their PostScript names, though nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your own custom `Text` in your app, you usually create a custom `Text` component ... and either use it directly in your screens ... or use it internally in your other **custom components** ... this way you're going to have consistent look and feel throughout your app

**Example**

You'd use `AppText` in your entire app ... and forget about `Text`

```
const AppText = ({ text }) => (
  <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'AmericanTypewriter', ...restOfYourStyles }}>
    {text}
  </Text>
);
```

Comment: I might solve it with a custom component, but I'm looking for a way to apply it to all text components without a custom component. I'd especially want to know why that particular example that everyone recommends is not working for my case.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Care to share any feedback on how you got on? Or mark a correct answer for others?

Comment: @MossPalmer you're right my bad. I could never get `defaultProps` to work and abandoned using it, and I've gone with inheriting from a common class just as the example in this answer. forgot to accept it.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Thanks for updating, that looks like the route I'm going too. Thanks for updating :)

Answer (score 5):

Add this before changing `fontFamily` style

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';

Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
```