# how can I prevent device zoom level effect on my app?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to RN, I make my app responsive to almost any device and my issue is when user change the zoom level of the device from default to large or largest my app components get affected. so my question is how can I prevent this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45139699/3237884 this answer would be helpful