# Set a max size for text in a React native app

Tags: css, react-native, frontend, user-experience, typography

After launching our React Native app we are making minor tweaks to the font scaling as it relates to a users native preferences. One thing I've noticed about other apps like Facebook is that they set a min/max-size. I'm wondering how is this specified in the react native code base. Also are there any tools that will help UX designers to help specify this to devs so designs translate better to development.

So far, I've only found this for help.
[How to disable font scaling in React Native for IOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as below.

1. set width suitable as per available space in your view.
2. set noOfLines={1} , so if text will increase then ... will appear at end of {value}

Comment: There has to be an alternative as well though. Facebook hit's a max value and just stops growing in size.