# Is allowFontScaling=false in <Text/> component a bad practice?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

i'm currently coding my new **React Native** app and i tried to use it on my brother's phone and i noticed the font size of most of the `<Text/>` components look bigger on his phone, and i was reading a lot of documentation and Github discussions until i found that `allowFontScaling={false}` was my solution, the `<Text/>` looks equal in both devices (**i thought my problem was fixed**), later i read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app) and people say it's a bad practice. I don't actually like the bad practices, so i'm not sure if implement it.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app). Yes, using `allowFontScaling=false` in `<Text/>` component is a bad practice. Because endusers may prefer the font size used on that device comfortable.

if you must use these below code, however try the different font size in different devices, and use the average font size. It may work.

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript add this line to your `App.tsx` | your entry page

```
interface TextWithDefaultProps extends Text {
    defaultProps?: { allowFontScaling?: boolean };
}

((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps =
((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {};
((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps!.allowFontScaling = false;
```