# Does React Native pass fontSize unchanged to the native OS widget?

Tags: react-native

Does React Native pass fontSize unchanged to the native OS widget? I'm trying to debug discrepancy between the mock (Figma) and implementation and want to rule out any conversions of the font size happening in RN.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale all text in your app, you can write custom scaleText() function, that will be scale your text according (PixelRatio) current running device. Check [this article](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio) for more information.

If you want to disable native OS scaling TextInput or Text, you can read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807843/how-to-disable-font-scaling-in-react-native-for-ios-app).

Try to do, something like that:

```
index.js file

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

//ADD this
if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
Text.defaultProps = {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}

if (TextInput.defaultProps == null) {
TextInput.defaultProps = {};
TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
}
```

I hope its help you.